# dd a class="" to anchor on the "read more" links of a node

Tags: nodes, theming

How I can add a class="" to anchor on the "read more" links of a node.
Im use a bootstrap theme and i need add de btn-default class to anchors, thanks

`<ul class="links list-inline">
  <li class="node-readmore first last">
    <<<<<<<< SET A CLASS IN THIS ANCHOR ? >>>>>>>>>>
    <a title="Noticia 2" rel="tag" href="/jnd/node/13">
      Read more
      <span class="element-invisible"> sobre Noticia 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add template.php file to your theme directory if it doesn't exist. Then, add [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) to it like so, replacing template with your theme name.

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  $variables['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-default';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but I is not working

Comment: Im use drupal 7 and drupal bootstrap 3

Comment: Did you clear the cache once you added the function? What is the name of your bootstrap subtheme?

Comment: function bootstrap_subtheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
$variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['attributes']['class'][] = 'btn btn-default';
}

It´s works to me, thanks for the help

Comment: And now I need add class to all links no only node-readmore